# Cursor type: move ONLY when drag

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, draggable

I implemented an element to have a drag function using `JQuery UI` with a cursor type of "move". I have an element, that's nested in the `draggable div`, let's call it 'inner', which has an `onclick` event, and when you hover over it, the cursor changes to "pointer" (through CSS).

**What I Want to Achieve:**

- I want the cursor to be "move" whenever you drag it, no matter what element your mouse is on, whether it's on `inner` or `draggable`.
- I also want `inner` to have a cursor type of "pointer" whenever hovered or clicked on. But once you start dragging it, the cursor should change to "move".

**What Actually Happens**

When the cursor is on `inner`, and you start dragging, the cursor stays "pointer", it doesn't change to "move".

I tried:

```
#draggable *:active {
  cursor: move;
}
```

what happens is, when you click not drag `inner`, the cursor changes to "move".

How can I make the cursor become "move" only when you drag the div?

#### JSFiddle

```js
$('#draggable').draggable({
  cursor: "move"
});

$('#inner').click(function() {
  $(this).css('background-color', 'orange');
});
```

```css
#draggable {
  background-color: pink;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
#inner {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
}
#inner:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
/*
#draggable *:active {
  cursor: move;
}
*/
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<style type="text/css"></style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css">



<div id="draggable">
  <div id="inner"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The class `.ui-draggable-dragging` is added to the element when it is being dragged.

Therefore, you can use this class to determine if the `#inner` element is being dragged. Just use the  selector `.ui-draggable-dragging #inner`, and set `cursor: move`:

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/p93pgrnr/)

```
#inner {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.ui-draggable-dragging #inner {
  cursor: move;
}
```

```js
$('#draggable').draggable({
  cursor: "move"
});

$('#inner').click(function() {
  $(this).css('background-color', 'orange');
});
```

```css
#draggable {
  background-color: pink;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
#inner {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
}
#inner {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.ui-draggable-dragging #inner {
  cursor: move;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<style type="text/css"></style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css">



<div id="draggable">
  <div id="inner"></div>
</div>
```

Since jQuery UI is already setting `cursor: move` on the `body` element when the element is being dragged, you can also just override `cursor: pointer` with `cursor: inherit`:

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/eb4mf1bj/)

```
#inner {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.ui-draggable-dragging #inner {
  cursor: inherit;
}
```

---

It's also worth mentioning that you can achieve this with a single selector by negating the `.ui-draggable` element if it has a class of `.ui-draggable-dragging`:

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/yc3y977r/)

```
.ui-draggable:not(.ui-draggable-dragging) #inner {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Didn't realize that! It's also important to note, that `.ui-draggable-dragging #inner {
  cursor: move;
}` should come **after**  `#inner {
  cursor: pointer;
}
` Just like you did in the example